# How to detect OpenMP parallelizable regions?

Tags: parallel-processing, profiling, openmp

I am currently working on a large code with many previous developers, which is heavily fragmented into plenty of classes. While OOP design is pretty good, the code itself runs very slow and I would like to make it faster using OpenMP.

The problem is, that I have no previous experience with finding possibly parallelizable regions in such a large code - are there any good tools/profilers, which can do that?

---

So far I've found this:

- Intel Advisor ([Tutorial](https://software.intel.com/en-us/get-started-with-advisor))

Comment: Have you used any code-execution **profiler** to collect hard facts about run-time spent in whichever part of the code? **What is the span of the code?** - i.e. **how many [ man*years ]** of efforts **were spent on the code-base** before you started your thoughts on moving the code-base into re-factoring via OpenMP?

Comment: @user3666197 I've used `gprof` to get some rough idea about run-time. Also, It's been developed for about 18months, mostly in a team of 3 or 4 people.

Comment: So, what hot-spots have you found in the profiling data? What are the reasons for each of the hot-spot(s) to last so long - network-transfer latencies, I/O-ops, CPU-computations, MEM-I/O-transfer latencies, other ... ?